# IDirect3D9::CheckDeviceType returns D3DERR_NOTAVAILABLE when application is started on boot on a headless graphics capable Ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, winapi, amazon-ec2, directx, direct3d

I have written an application that launches unity applications on a AWS Ec2 instance that needs hardware acceleration to render properly. This launcher application does a pre-sanity check to make sure a HAL (hardware acceleration) device is present with Direct3D calls like

```
D3DDISPLAYMODE mode;
HRESULT hr;
if (FAILED (hr = s_D3D->GetAdapterDisplayMode (g_D3DAdapter, &mode)))
{
   return false;
}

if(FAILED (hr = s_D3D->CheckDeviceType (g_D3DAdapter, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, mode.Format, mode.Format, TRUE)))
{
   /// This fails.
   return false;
}
```

The sanity check succeeds when I run the launcher application from remote desktop as expected. But it fails when the application is launched on boot.

If I remove the sanity checks the unity application loads correctly on boot but certain elements/shaders that do need hardware acceleration are not rendered properly.

I am using a AWS EC2 G4 Instance with Windows10 and NVIDIA Tesla T4 graphics card. I have the latest drivers (Nvidia and Directx) installed as well.

For extra debugging I have tried printing some debug logs to see if the graphics driver was even detected and the application does seem to find it.

```
D3DADAPTER_IDENTIFIER9 adapter_info;
hr = s_D3D->GetAdapterIdentifier (g_D3DAdapter, 0, &adapter_info);
std::cout << "Device Name: " << adapter_info.DeviceName << std::endl;
std::cout << "Device Id: " << std::to_string (adapter_info.DeviceId) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Device Desc: " << adapter_info.Description << std::endl;
std::cout << "Device Driver: " << adapter_info.Driver << std::endl;
```

If you are curious as to how I am launching the application process on boot I use the AWS's UserDataScripts feature. Through the UserData scripts I make sure that the application process is running with administrator privileges and under the correct windows session. Following is a link that talks about the approach I am using.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-32-and-64-bit-Archite

I haven't found anything close on this topic from the searches I have done so far.

Comment: Legacy Direct3D 9 can't access HAL devices in a 'headless' mode due to session 0 isolation. Direct3D9Ex, Direct3D 11, etc. should be able to find HAL devices, however.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I make sure the unity game are launched on session 1, does that mean Direct3D 9 has issues with accessing HAL devices in headless mode irrespective of the session?

Comment: Legacy Direct3D 9 considers all 'headless scenarios' to be a LOST DEVICE. You have to use newer DXGI-aware APIs like Direct3D9Ex, Direct3D11, etc. to actually access HAL from a headless (i.e. not logged in) scenario, and it must be Windows 8 or later.